# MySQL: How do I select all the entries from a table WHERE NAME = '$name'

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how to select all the entries from the table where the NAME row = '$name'. For example, if the user has multiple messages in the table, it shows all of them. What I have so far is:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
```

And that only gets one. Please help! Thanks!
**What I mean is, get two values from one WHERE clause.**

Comment: If you have multiple  entries in your table then you need to use IN operator..

Comment: Your query seems correct. How do you get the data / show the results?

Comment: Can you post an example of your table structure?

Comment: If your column is actually called `name`, and you're passing in a single value in `$name`, your query should retrieve multiple rows. So either you've provided invalid information, or your code after the query is executed doesn't retrieve rows after the first. Either way, you need to improve your question with sample data, code that actually shows what you're doing, and supply the output you expect from the query. You've given no information to go on to try and help you here; a one-line code snippet with poor column, table, and variable names isn't enough.

Comment: Your query appears to be correct. That is, if you have a column called 'name' in the 'table' table then this query will return all exact matching rows where 'name' is equal to $name. How about a sample of the data in the table and the value of $name to analyze the problem further?

Comment: I actually just got one of the results back from that query (I had two where name = Bob Jenkins) so I was wondering how to get two of them back where name = Bob Jenkins.

Comment: @SnarkyDTheman: Please read the comments above. Two of us have said that you're not retrieving the rows after the first one, and asked for your code. If you're not willing to provide it, we can't possibly show you why it's not working. Please edit your question and add the info we've asked for if you want help solving the problem. If you don't need help any longer, please delete the question so people don't waste time trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks correct so I am wondering if it's a problem with PHP. Try doing this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br />";
}
```

This should show you how many result rows you get back. The same way you can change the 'name' parameter to get any other field from your result set.

Comment: I actually just got one of the results back from that query (I had two where name = Bob Jenkins) so I was wondering how to get two of them back where name = Bob Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '".$name."'";
```